# Как прописать, минимум от 20 символов, для сообщений?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите, как прописать, в текстовый хендлер, чтобы в 1 сообщении, в группе телеграм, минимум, от 20 символов, если меньше, чтобы сообщение удалялось и устанавливались ограничения, пользователь не сможет, написать в группе.

Вот код, прописал, для удаления и установки ограничений, но сейчас, удаляет и ставит ограничения, на любое сообщение, как его прописать, чтобы если меньше 20 символов, удалял и устанавливал ограничения.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def get_handler(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    name = message.from_user.full_name
    chat_id = message.chat.id

    if message.text:
        await message.delete()
        await bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, ChatPermissions(disable_notification=True, timeout=None), until_date=time() + 54000)
        return
```

Comment: `len(message.text)`

Comment: Подскажите, куда это прописать и как прописать, от 20 символов?

Comment: if len(message.text): верно?

Comment: ну вы посмотрите, что выведет `len(message.text)`, а дальше сообразите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

советую изучить хотя бы основы python

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def get_handler(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    name = message.from_user.full_name
    chat_id = message.chat.id

    if len(message.text) < 20:
        await message.delete()
        await bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, ChatPermissions(disable_notification=True, timeout=None), until_date=time() + 54000)
        return
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё равно удаляет

Comment: может, какой то импорт, надо прописать?

Comment: ну удаляет если меньше 20 символов в тексте, если вы напишите "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролдж" то удалять не будет

Comment: Благодарю, вопрос решен, всё работает. Всем спасибо.